# regex mixed case excluding specific case

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I need a regex able to match:

- a) **All** combinations of lower-/upper-cases of a certain word
- b) **Except** a couple of certain case-combinations.

I must search the `bash` thru thousands of source-code files, occurrences of **miss-spelled** variables.

Specifically, the word I'm searching for is `FrontEnd` which in our coding-style guide can be written exactly in 2 ways depending on the context:

```
FrontEnd (F and E upper)
frontend (all lower)
```

So I need to "catch" any occurences that do not follow our coding standards as:

```
frontEnd
FRONTEND
fRonTenD
```

I have been reading many tutorials of regex for this specific example and I cannot find a way to say "match this pattern BUT do not match if it is exactly this one or this other one".

I guess it would be similar to trying to match "any number between 000000 to 999999, except exactly the number 555555 or the number 123456", I suppose the logic is similar (of course I don't knot to do this either :) )

Thnx

---

Additional comment:

I cannot use `grep` piped to `grep -v` because I could miss lines; for example if I do:

```
grep -i frontend | grep -v FrontEnd | grep -v frontend
```

would miss a line like this:

```
if( frontEnd.name == 'hello' || FrontEnd.value == 3 )
```

because the second occurence would hide the whole line. Therefore I'm searching for a regex to use with `egrep` capable to do the exact match I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this easily with `egrep` because it doesn't support lookaheads.  It's probably easiest to do this with perl.

```
perl -ne 'print if /(?!frontend|FrontEnd)(?i)frontend/;'
```

To use just pipe the text through `stdin`

How this works:

```
perl -ne 'print if /(?!frontend|FrontEnd)(?i)frontend/;'
^     ^^  ^     ^  ^ ^ ^                 ^   ^ The pattern that matches both the correct and incorrect versions.
|     ||  |     |  | | |                 | This switch turns on case insensitive matching for the rest of the regular expression (use (?-i) to turn it off) (perl specific)
|     ||  |     |  | | | The pattern that match the correct versions.
|     ||  |     |  | | Negative forward look ahead, ensures that the good stuff won't be matched
|     ||  |     |  | Begin regular expression match, returns true if match
|     ||  |     | Begin if statement, this expression uses perl's reverse if semantics (expression1 if expression2;)
|     ||  | Print content of $_, which is piped in by -n flag
|     || Evaluate perl code from command line
|     | Wrap code in while (<>) { } takes each line from stdin and puts it in $_
| Perl command, love it or hate it.
```

Comment: Like a charm!!!! That does EXACTLY what I needed. Thanx OmnipotentEntity. Particularly I've used it inside a `find -exec` and passing `{}` to the perl so it "detects" those singularities among thousands of files.

Answer (score 0):

This really should be a comment, but is there any reason you cannot use `sed`? I'm thinking something like

```
sed 's/frontend/FrontEnd/ig' input.txt
```

That is, of course, assuming you want to correct the deviant versions...

Comment: There's a reason: the "good version" `FrontEnd` or `frontend` is not interchangeable, it depends on the context. So we cannot substitute "all occurences of bad-spelled" into `FrontEnd` (as that `sed` would do) because some should be converted to `FrontEnd` whilst others should read `frontend`. We are seeking a way to display those in the screen to manually choose the correct replacement.

Comment: I know, but I thought "valid as well" meant that it didn't matter what way it was written in. Oh well, it was worth a try; I was just trying to sidestep the issue, really. Maybe someone can turn this answer into a comment?